# Split 2d string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I got a `string[ ][ ]`, for example `{{a,b}{c,d}}`.
How could convert it to string or using split method to display `string[ ][ ]` properly?

```
     string[][] result;
     result = test.AnagramsFinder(inputArray); //which returns string[][]
     string value = string.Join(";",result); // this line does not work for me
     Label1.Text = value ;
```

is only for `string[ ]`, but not `string[ ][ ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.Join(";", result.Select(a => String.Join(",", a)).ToArray());
```

**Output:**

> a,b;c,d

Comment: Thanks for posting. btw, do u how to check if a nested list does not contain a string value?

Comment: @user1805430 String.Join(";", result.Where(x => (!x.Contains(StringToAvoid))).Select(a => String.Join(",", a)).ToArray());

Answer (score 3):

For an **"a, b, c, d"** result:

```
 string value = string.Join(", ", result.SelectMany(a => a));
```

and for the **"a, b; c, d"** option:

```
string value = string.Join("; ", result.Select(a => string.Join(", ", a))) ;
```

Comment: Where is the separator?, it receives two arguments

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. Any ideas how could I split those arrays by using ";" between arrays and "," between elements in single array?

Comment: Yeah, forgot that. Fixed some typos now.

Comment: @user1805430 - as the name of the function indicates, this is Joining, not Splitting strings.

Comment: Thanks. btw, do u how to check if a nested list does not contain a string value?

Comment: Nested list? This was about `string[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I cannot follow your usecase for this:

```
using System.Linq;

string[][] result;
result = test.AnagramsFinder(inputArray); //which returns string[][]
string value = string.Join(";",result.SelectMany(x=> x)); 
Label1.Text = value ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

string value = string.Join(";",result.Selectmany(x => x);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. But I don't have definition for Selectmany..Did I miss any reference?

Comment: Yeah, you have to use: using System.Linq; Import it at the beginning of the class

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a nice string representation of your array you can use the following code:

```
Label1.Text = result
    .Select(item => item.Aggregate((left,right) => left + "," + right))
    .Aggregate((left , right) => left + "|" + right);
```

for a give input array

```
var input = new[] {new[]{"a", "b"}, new[]{"c", "d"}};
```

this delivers the result

```
a,b|c,d
```